# Installed and Still "No module named 'scipy'"

Tags: python, windows

Done ALL suggested in SO.
[image]

This is what I have done on my Windows 10:

1. Install Python 3.9 for **All** users, verified working and in the PATH.
   [image]
   [image]
2. downloaded corresponding numpy from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), `pip3 install numpy-1.20.3+vanilla-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` successfully.
3. downloaded corresponding ndimage from the same site, `pip3 install ndimage-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl --force-reinstall` successful.
   [image]
4. cv2 and numpy good:
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where your command of the `scipy` installation?

Comment: didi you `pip install scipy`?

Comment: Can you please try `which pip` (or pip3) to get the location of the pip installation  to make sure it is for the same python. After that please run `pip list` to list all installed modules.

Comment: @BrownBear inside `C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts`

Comment: @MatteoZanoni I did `pip3 install ndimage-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl --force-reinstall` which is the `scipy.ndimage`. Then after it said successfully, tried `import scipy.ndimage` got error.

Comment: I believe you should install both scipy and ndimage to get the code working. Try running `pip install scipy` in addition to the steps you already did.

Comment: @kinshukdua Please see updated post above. Somehow `which pip` and `which python` are not recognized.

Comment: What output do you get when you run `pip install scipy`

Comment: @kinshukdua Please see post above, item 3.

Comment: @Jeb50 that says `numpy` and `ndimag` installed not the complete package `scipy`. Was that the output to installing scipy? Try running these commands and lmk if they work: `import scipy.ndimage` or `import ndimage` or `from scipy import ndimage`

Comment: @kinshukdua Please bottom of the post. What's the diff between `ndimage` and `scipy.ndimage`?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like there is a compiled version yet for 3.9.5  The max version I see is for python 3.9.4

https://winpython.github.io/

Comment: I did also tried `winPython` just didn't know how to proceed to add more module/packages after had that installed. Can you please shed some lights?

Comment: Honestly I would uninstall everything, and start with miniconda.  Then install modules using the conda command line, then use pip if that doesn't work.